# How to create file system and folders structure in Visio 2010?

Tags: tree, directory, visio

I am newbie to Visio 2010 and was wondering is there any way to create hierarchical diagram of directory tree? This folder tree might also include files and it doesn't need to actually exist in reality on my local hard drive, I'd just like to create it from within Visio 2010 by using Organizational Chart template for example.

I am .NET developer and I just want to create presentation of the folder structure of my Visual Studio project which is pretty large. There is source code folder, output folder, resources folder, 3rd party libs folder etc... each with containing some files. So, some visualization and diagrams would be very useful when explaining the project structure to my coworkers. I was searching and googling for Visio templates for this purpose but unfortunately didn't find any. I am not sure if I should use Visio 2010 for this purpose but I know it's the most famous diagraming tool available so I assumed there could be an feature for this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [org chart wizard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/create-an-organization-chart-HA010357090.aspx)

You would need to get your project structure into the format the wizard can understand and then it will do the rendering for you.

If that doesn't give enough control, it's not too hard to write some code that will automate Visio to draw what you need.